# Need to start a code line after react subscribe() functions end

Tags: kotlin, reactor

```
val totalNumInst = TotalNumObj()

        devSupportService.sendAllTalktalkMessages(naverId)
        devSupportService.sendAllAutoDepositTalktalkMessages(naverId, totalNum)
        logger.info("${totalNumInst.totalNum}")
```

```
Mono<>
.doOnSuccess { }
.subscribe()
```

First two lines execute several Mono<>.subscribe() functions. In each Mono<>'s .doOnSuccess{} the `totalNum` variable is increasing. At the last line, I added a log which shows `totalNum`. But the `totalNum` variable always shows the initial value, 0.

I need to leave a log which shows how many times does the Mono<>.subscribe() is executed.
Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Reactive code is different than the non-reactive one. That is why you need to chain your calls and also the logging statement. What does `sendAllTalktalkMessages` and `sendAllAutoDepositTalktalkMessages`methods return?

Comment: These two functions return nothing, just call many 
```
Mono<>
.doOnSuccess { }
.subscribe()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of solving your issue. The blocking and non-blocking.

**Blocking**

create a countDownLatch, pass it to sendAllTalktalkMessages and sendAllAutoDepositTalktalkMessages, then wait for it being latched

```
val totalNumInst = TotalNumObj()
val latch = CountDownLatch(2)

devSupportService.sendAllTalktalkMessages(naverId, totalNumInst, latch)
devSupportService.sendAllAutoDepositTalktalkMessages(naverId, totalNumInst, latch)

if (!latch.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
    throw TimeoutException("Waiting timed out")
}
logger.info("${totalNumInst.totalNum}")
```

And add `latch.countDown()` to each `doOnSuccess` (but I'd recommend to countDown in doFinally in case of the chain sending error signal)

```
Mono<>
    .doOnSuccess { latch.countDown() }
    .subscribe()
```

This is blocking solution, it is against reactive non-blocking concept.

**Non-blocking**

Make sendAllTalktalkMessages and sendAllAutoDepositTalktalkMessages returning Mono and zip them (moreover in that case you don't need to pass totalNumInst to them)

```
Mono.zip(
    devSupportService.sendAllTalktalkMessages(naverId)
        .map { 1 }
        .onErrorResume { Mono.just(0) }
        .defaultIfEmpty(0),
    devSupportService.sendAllAutoDepositTalktalkMessages(naverId)
        .map { 1 }
        .onErrorResume { 0 }
        .defaultIfEmpty(0)
) { counter1, counter2 -> counter1 + counter2 }
.subscribe { totalNum -> logger.info("$totalNum") }
```

in this realisation you count each success as 1 and each error or empty signal as 0.